# Show different content in lightbox when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, lightbox

I am new to javascript/jquery and I currently have a problem with showing different content in lightbox upon button click with javascript/jquery

I have created two buttons which is supposed to show a lightbox with different content when button is clicked. The content inside the lightbox should be different for each button which is not the case at the moment.

When I try to change the first `h3` and `p` tag for the first button, it just overlaps the second `h3` and `p` tag for the second button. I believe the problem lies in the javascript code, but I can't figure out how to show different content for each lightbox upon button click.

Here is my HTML/Javascript code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="no">
<head>
  <title>FantasyLab</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
 
      $(document).ready(function(){
 
        $('.lightbox').click(function(){
          $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
          $('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
          $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
        });
 
        $('.close').click(function(){
          close_box();
        });
 
        $('.backdrop').click(function(){
          close_box();
        });
 
      });
 
      function close_box()
      {
        $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
          $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
        });
      } 

  </script>
 
  </script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#060e19">

<div class="page-wrap">
  
    <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="contact">Kom i kontakt</a>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="close"><i class="fa fa-times fa-1x"></i></div> <!-- end of close -->
    <h3 class="title">Kom i kontakt</h3>
    <p>Kontakt oss for mer informasjon</p>
      <div class="container">  
        <form id="newsletter-subscription" action="" method="post">
          <fieldset>
            <input placeholder="Fornavn" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
          </fieldset> <!-- end of fieldset -->
          <fieldset>
            <input placeholder="Etternavn" type="text" tabindex="2" required autofocus>
          </fieldset> <!-- end of fieldset -->
          <fieldset>
            <input placeholder="E-postadresse" type="email" tabindex="3" required>
          </fieldset> <!-- end of fieldset -->
          <fieldset>
            <input placeholder="Telefonnummer" type="tel" tabindex="4" required>
          </fieldset> <!-- end of fieldset -->
          <fieldset>
            <input placeholder="Webside http://" type="url" tabindex="5" required>
          </fieldset> <!-- end of fieldset -->
          <fieldset>
            <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Send inn</button>
          </fieldset>
        </form> <!-- end of form -->
      </div> <!-- end of container -->
  </div> <!-- end of box-content -->



  <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="subscribe">Meld deg på vår nyhetsbrev</a>
  <div class="backdrop"></div> <!-- end of backdrop -->
  <div class="box">
    <div class="close"><i class="fa fa-times fa-1x"></i></div> <!-- end of close -->
    <h3 class="title">Abonner på nyhetsbrev</h3>
    <p>Motta informasjon rundt lanseringsdato, kampanjer og tilbud.</p>
      <div class="container">  
        <form id="newsletter-subscription" action="" method="post">
          <fieldset>
            <input placeholder="Fornavn" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
          </fieldset> <!-- end of fieldset -->
          <fieldset>
            <input placeholder="Etternavn" type="text" tabindex="2" required autofocus>
          </fieldset> <!-- end of fieldset -->
          <fieldset>
            <input placeholder="E-postadresse" type="email" tabindex="3" required>
          </fieldset> <!-- end of fieldset -->
          <fieldset>
            <input placeholder="Telefonnummer" type="tel" tabindex="4" required>
          </fieldset> <!-- end of fieldset -->
          <fieldset>
            <input placeholder="Webside http://" type="url" tabindex="5" required>
          </fieldset> <!-- end of fieldset -->
          <fieldset>
            <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Send inn</button>
          </fieldset>
        </form> <!-- end of form -->
      </div> <!-- end of container -->
  </div> <!-- end of box-content -->
  
  </div> <!-- end of main-content -->
      
</div> <!-- end of page-wrap -->


</body>

</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues I see immediately - If you want the content to change when you click the button, that's what you have to attach the .click() to, not your .lighthouse class. But you've given both of your buttons the same id, so if you want to select by id you have to change one of them. something like:

```
$('#contact-submit-first').click(function(){
    //change content on first button click
});

 $('#contact-submit-second').click(function(){
    //change content on second button click
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to have two separate buttons which open two different lightbox, you have to review you're code :

- First, you need to think your jQuery so that it select the content depending on the button clicked :

  ```
  $('.lightbox').click(function(){
      $(this).next('.box').addClass('active');
  });

  $('.close').click(function(){
      $(this).parent('.box').removeClass('active');
  });
  ```
- Then, you use CSS3 to manage the animations :

  ```
  .box {
      display: none;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all 0.4s ease;
  }

  .box.active {
      opacity: 1;
      display: block;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a double "" in your code, probably from copy & paste... and you have two includes of two different jquery versions (1.8.3 and 1.5.2), which can produce unexpected behaviour.

You want to have one lightbox that changes its title and description based on the clicked link. There are many ways to do this, in your current html you got the problem that you have elements with the same IDs more than once, which will produce strange effects propable.
So let's first remove the second lightbox alltogether.

Then you need to save the information about title and description somewhere so the javascript can retrieve it, i would suggest data attributes like this:

```
<a href="#lbContact" class="lightbox" id="contact" data-box-title="Kom i kontakt" data-box-description="Kontakt oss for mer informasjon">
    Kom i kontakt
</a>
<a href="#lbContact" class="lightbox" id="subscribe" data-box-title="Abonner på nyhetsbrev" data-box-description="Motta informasjon rundt lanseringsdato, kampanjer og tilbud.">
    Meld deg på vår nyhetsbrev
</a>
```

I added the target lightbox in the href as well.

The javascript could then look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.lightbox').click(function(){
        // Get the hash attribute from the clicked link/button
        var targetLightbox = $(this.hash);
        var link = $(this);

        var title = link.data("box-title");
        var description = link.data("box-description");

        // Copy title and description into the lightbox
        targetLightbox.find(".title").text(title);
        targetLightbox.find(".description").text(description);


        $('.backdrop').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
        $('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
        $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
    });

    // Hide the lightbox and backdrop
    $('.close, .backdrop').click(function(){
        $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
            $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
        });
    });

  });
```

I created a fiddle for a possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Macavity/d84vft2k/1/